# Simulate a reservation: Compare hour, date and Classroom between Java and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

Good day. I have a small Java program that simulates the reservation of a class schedule. I need to reserve a classroom, on a specific date and a class start time and specific class end time, if there is a record in the database with those parameters (same date, hours and classroom) you can not make the reservation, however my ResultSet does not work. This is my method to create a reservation (cbxs are ComboBox):

```
public void crearReserva(String cbx1, String cbx2, String cbx3, Date fecha, String horaInicial, String horaFinal) {
        try {
            ResultSet retorno = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM horarios WHERE horarios.hinicio >= '" + horaInicial + "' OR horarios.hfin <= '" + horaFinal + "' AND horarios.nomambiente = '" + cbx3 + "' AND horarios.fecha = '" + fecha + "'");
            if (!retorno.next()) {
                s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO horarios VALUES ('" + cbx1 + "', '" + cbx2 + "', '" + cbx3 + "', '" + fecha + "', '" + horaInicial + "', '" + horaFinal + "')");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Reserva realizada exitosamente!", "Operación Exitosa", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se puede reservar el " + cbx3 + " en la fecha y horas especificadas. Ya hay una reserva existente.\nRevise la tabla para hallar un espacio disponible en la formación.", "Espacio Ocupado", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
            //retorno.beforeFirst();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConexionMySQL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

I do not have connection problems, in fact everything works fine, except that it does not work as it should be. If I insert exactly what is in a previous record, I do not want to create the insert, however if the start time or the end time change, the insertion is created, it should not be so.

"Ambiente" = Classroom, "Fecha" = Date, "Hora Inicio" = Start Time, "Hora Final" = Final Time, "cbx" = ComboBox

[Here is how the second record has been made (between the hours of 8:00 a.m. - 11:30 a.m.) despite the fact that the first record has an interval of time between 7:00 a.m. - 12:00 p.m.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0Atz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query needs to be

```
"SELECT * FROM horarios WHERE horarios.hfin > '" + horaInicial + "' AND horarios.hinicio < '" + horaFinal + "' AND horarios.nomambiente = '" + cbx3 + "' AND horarios.fecha = '" + fecha + "'"
```

since this is the condition for the two bookings to overlap.

Also, you should probably use a `PreparedStatement` with a bunch of parameters, to avoid any risk of SQL injection.